# Accessing Nested JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to pull data from Behance.net and I'm running into two issues when I try to get the information.

The first issue is trying to pull the description of the project.  I can get the information by calling `ng-bind="project.description"` but the formatting (paragraph returns) is not present, so I'm trying to pull the formatted description.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3 ng-bind="project.name"></h3>
    <p ng-bind="project.modules.text"></p>

    <h4><i class="fa fa-tags success"></i> Tags</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="pull-left label label-info" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:10px;"
              ng-repeat="tag in project.tags" ng-bind="tag"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JSON data Behance is showing:

```
angular.callbacks._0({
    "project": {
    ....
         "modules": [{
            "id": 111549713,
            "type": "text",
            "text": "This is the description of the project I am trying to get"
```

My second issue I'm guessing is the same as the first, but here it is.

```
<p style="margin-top:10px;" ng-bind="user.sections.About"></p>
```

and the JSON file:

```
angular.callbacks._1({
    "user": {
       "sections": {
            "About Me": Description used on the behance website that I am trying to display
```

I can pull any information except these two instances.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue:**

`project.modules` is an array, so try this instead:

```
<p ng-bind="project.modules[0].text"></p>
```

**Second issue:**

As the property 'About Me' contains a space you will need to use the bracket notation to access it:

```
<p style="margin-top:10px;" ng-bind="user.sections['About Me']"></p>
```